# Animation in gdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm pretty new in [LibGDX](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) and Android Studio.

I'm trying to create a simple animation using 8 png files, the animation happens but it's so fast and unrealistic.

Is there a way to put a delay between frames?.
Thanks.

```
public class Runningrabbit extends ApplicationAdapter {
  SpriteBatch batch;
  Texture background;
  Texture[] rabbits;
  int rabbitState = 0;
  float stateTime;

  @Override
  public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    background = new Texture("back.png");
    rabbits = new Texture[8];
    rabbits[0] = new Texture("rabbit1.png");
    rabbits[1] = new Texture("rabbit2.png");
    rabbits[2] = new Texture("rabbit3.png");
    rabbits[3] = new Texture("rabbit4.png");
    rabbits[4] = new Texture("rabbit5.png");
    rabbits[5] = new Texture("rabbit6.png");
    rabbits[6] = new Texture("rabbit7.png");
    rabbits[7] = new Texture("rabbit8.png");



    stateTime = 0f;
  }

  @Override
  public void render () {

    if (rabbitState == 0) {
      rabbitState = 1;
    } else if (rabbitState == 1) {
      rabbitState = 2;
    } else if (rabbitState == 2) {
       rabbitState = 3;
    } else if (rabbitState == 3) {
      rabbitState = 4;
    } else if (rabbitState == 4) {
      rabbitState = 5;
    } else if (rabbitState == 5) {
      rabbitState = 6;
    } else if (rabbitState == 6) {
      rabbitState = 7;
    } else if (rabbitState == 7) {
      rabbitState = 0;
    }

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(background, 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    batch.draw(rabbits[rabbitState], 200, 200);
    batch.end();

  }
}
```

Comment: libGDX has an Animation class exactly for this purpose. Much easier than rolling your own. Check out the API docs

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the changing of the animation's state depend on time.

for example,

```
float accumulator = 0f;

...

public void render(){

     float dt = Gdx.graphics.deltaTime(); //dt is the number of seconds that have passed in between each frame
     accumulator += dt;
     if(accumulator > 1)//one second has passed{
         rabbitState++;
         accumulator -= 1;
     }

...
```

now, the animation will move forward once every second (which is painfully slow, but you can adjust then number).

Beyond your question, two things that I noticed looking through your code are:

1. You're making a new texture for each frame. Don't do this, have a texture with all the frames and make texture regions. There's no point in using a SpriteBatch if it needs to swap textures every single draw call.
2. There's an animation class in LibGDX as someone else has pointed out, it'll save you a lot of hassle to just use it.
3. You're manually changing the state with if statements when you just have to increment your index.